# openlayers3 undefined is not a constructor error on ol.source.StaticVector

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson

I am learning openlayers3 with ol v3.20.1
I've got to the point in the book, where I can read/write GeoJSON with StaticVector, but the following code:

```html
var statVec = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.StaticVector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
 })
});
```

errors out with:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new ol.source.StaticVector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })')
    global code
```

I realize, there was an API change, since the book came out, but I can't find what StaticVector was replaced with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ol.source.StaticVector` along with other similar experimental Vector sources were removed in **v3.5.0**.  Regarding your question `ol.source.StaticVector` is replaced with `ol.source.Vector`.

See this release details

> https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v3.5.0

Comment: Yes, thank You. It helped, but 'StaticVector' is not mentioned anywhere in the resource, you've shared with the link.

Comment: Yes its not mentioned but i dont know why? `ol.source.ServerVector` similar to it is mentioned and removed in this version